# Using Python map function with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox

Script is simple made for this case. Creating new shapes based on known arguments.

**My code:**

```
import arcpy

#variables
fc_1 = 'fc_1'
fc_2 = 'fc_2'
fc_3 = 'fc_3'
fc_4 =  'fc_4'
war_1 = "highway = 'path'"
war_2 = "highway = 'motorway'"
war_3 = "natural = 'water'",
war_4 = "leisure = 'pitch'",
suffix_1 = '1'
suffix_2 = '2'
suffix_3 = '3'
suffix_4 = '4'
temp = 'temp_layer'

def select_save(fc, temp, war, suffix):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, temp)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(temp, "NEW_SELECTION", war)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(temp, '{0}_{1}'.format(fc, suffix)

arcpy.env.workspace = r'gdb_path'

select_save(fc_1, temp, war_1, suffix_1)
select_save(fc_2, temp, war_2, suffix_2)
select_save(fc_3, temp, war_3, suffix_3)
select_save(fc_4, temp, war_4, suffix_4)
```

So how to get rid of those copy-pasted function calls?
In my current project I need to call my function 20-30 times. It looks horrible to see this wall of text.

Answer (score 1):

To do so I used **itertools.starmap** function:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap

**Why starmap not map?**

Starmap eliminates need of using lambda function to iterate through tuple.

---

I started off with tuple which contains all arguments needed to call starmap.

```
tuple_args = [(fc_1, temp, war_1, suffix_1),
          (fc_2, temp, war_2, suffix_2),
          (fc_2, temp, war_3, suffix_3),
          (fc_3, temp, war_4, suffix_4)]
```

Final code looked like this:

```
import arcpy
from itertools import starmap
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#variables
fc_1 = 'fc_1'
fc_2 = 'fc_2'
fc_3 = 'fc_3'
fc_4 =  'fc_4'
war_1 = "highway = 'path'"
war_2 = "highway = 'motorway'"
war_3 = "natural = 'water'",
war_4 = "leisure = 'pitch'",
suffix_1 = '1'
suffix_2 = '2'
suffix_3 = '3'
suffix_4 = '4'
temp = 'temp_layer'

def select_save(fc, temp, war, suffix):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, temp)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(temp, "NEW_SELECTION", war)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(temp, '{0}_{1}'.format(fc, suffix)

arcpy.env.workspace = r'gdb_path'

tuple_args = [(fc_1, temp, war_1, suffix_1),
          (fc_2, temp, war_2, suffix_2),
          (fc_2, temp, war_3, suffix_3),
          (fc_3, temp, war_4, suffix_4)]

list(starmap(select_save, tuple_args))
```

Remeber to put starmap(...) inside of list, beacuse if not there will be no output and you will see something like this:

> map at 0x2002a48c588